How to fix "Package zref-clever Warning: Reference format option 'Name-sg' undefined for type" for an unnumbered section (when cross-referencing)
How to fix the following warning when adding an asterisk (*) at the end of the command \section and before the opening curly brace, in order to get an unnumbered section?
Package zref-clever Warning: Reference format option 'Name-sg' undefined for type '' on line 43.
‪(./supplementary.tex, 43‬)


You have referenced something which has not yet been labelled. If you have labelled it already, make sure that what is written inside \ref{...} is the same as what is written inside \label{...}.

Minimal Working Example (MWE) based on @gusbrs solution_1 and solution_2.
supplementary.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{zref-titleref} % after (sub)caption
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\zcsetup{cap,noabbrev,
  countertype={
    section=suppsection,
    table=supptable,
    figure=suppfigure,
    % And others you might need...
  },
}
% At begindocument since zref-clever sets this up in the compat module.
\AddToHook{begindocument}{\zcsetup{countertype={subfigure=suppfigure}}}

\zcLanguageSetup{english}{
  type = suppsection ,
    Name-sg = Section ,
    name-sg = section ,
    Name-pl = Sections ,
    name-pl = sections ,
  type = suppfigure ,
    Name-sg = Figure ,
    name-sg = figure ,
    Name-pl = Figures ,
    name-pl = figures ,
  type = supptable ,
    Name-sg = Table ,
    name-sg = table ,
    Name-pl = Tables ,
    name-pl = tables ,
  % And others you might need...
}

\begin{document}

\noindent In \zcref[ref=title,noname]{supp_text} we discuss about...

\section*{Supplementary text}
\label{supp_text}


blsa bla bla...

\end{document}



Unnumbered section commands don't call \refstepcounter, so they don't set the label data at all. Since in your document that's the first thing, your label is mostly empty, there's no label, no counter, no type. Normally, you'd get whatever the last call to \refstepcounter was, which would be mostly arbitrary for that label. You can use \nameref or equivalent, and that's what you are doing there. But \zcref is telling you it has no type name defined if the type is empty... It is just a warning. You could use \zref[title]{supp_text} (no hyperlink though). [...]

[...] I'm not sure I should remove the warning if noname is being used. Sounds like a corner case, and exception handling. True, that's the easy way to a hyperlink there, since zref itself doesn't, but still.

Thanks @gusbrs! I personally like the \zcref[ref=title,noname]{}... Unfortunately, \zref[title]{} loses the hyperlink, which is extremely useful... the best would be (if possible) to still be able to use \zcref[ref=title,noname]{} or something similar which preserves the hyperlink, without the warning... I mean... if \zcref[ref=title,noname]{} applied to unnumbered chapters, sections, etc.. does not mess up the rest of the document, I would then remove the warning... Well... this is just my personal taste as user of your (very useful!) package

Ommo, the thing is \zcref is not really meant to be a substitute for \nameref. I consider this a workaround given that zref does not provide hyperlinking. I'll think about this a bit.

Ah ok, I did not know about it... btw, \nameref is useful time to time - I think that something equivalent to it could be a precious tool for writing documents :-)

Ommo, just use \nameref then.  ;-)

Yes, thanks :-)

Ommo, I decided to inhibit the warning: https://github.com/gusbrs/zref-clever/commit/2fbdfadefaa7d62f96c4e235444e98cf411b7daa. Even if arguably a corner case, it does make sense. On the next release, the warning will be gone.

Cool! Thanks a lot! Since I am currently using Overleaf, I think I would need to wait the next release of TexLive (I guess the 2025, in the next summer) https://www.overleaf.com/blog/tex-live-2024-is-now-available in order to see yur modification :-)
